# ios build error? library not found ,How to fix this issue

Tags: ios

ld: library not found for -lLibraryName_iphonesimulatord clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: set bitcode to NO for the library.

Comment: @kevin i have already done it but still error exist

Comment: Does there app extension in your app? @davender Verma

Comment: doesn't gets your point @kavin mac .how i can do it

Comment: i'm asking that is there any extension included in your application.E.g keyboard extension. If there then you have to select target for the exntesion to add that library.

Comment: no such extension

Comment: still not working  @Kevin

Comment: you have set bitcode to NO for the library. Have you set it same for the project also? @davender

Comment: yes i have done it

Comment: At finally i have reset my entire project with the new one, now new app is working fine thanks for your support .i have learnt something new from your points @thanks